# Delete specific digit in a number using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a column named `membership_number` varchar(255) in the `memberships` table.

Here is some sample data:

0000001234
0000002345
0000003456

`membership_number` must have 10 digits. If a user enters a number that has less than 10 digits, then the missing places are filled with leading zeroes accordingly.

At the moment, I have some data in this column as follows:

00001234.0
00002345.1
00003456.2

I would like to delete the decimal point which is the 2nd to the last digit and then add a leading zero to handle all of these undesired membership numbers. What would be the best way to do this?

I am aware of SUBSTRING() and its parameters but couldn't make it work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please backup your data before trying this.**

Would that work?

```
UPDATE tablename SET membership_number = concat('0',replace(membership_number,'.','')) WHERE membership_number LIKE '%._'
```

Comment: Strings need to be enclosed in single quotes (`'`) in SQL, double quotes (`"`) can only be used with identifiers

Comment: I tested it with dummy data and it works for me. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Substring is not the function you want, you want a combination of [REPLACE and LPAD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html) functions:

```
 select lpad( replace (membership_number, '.', ''), 10, '0')  
   from menberships;
```

(table name assumed) And why if it must be 10 digits do you define it as length up to 255?